# Databricks : structure stream data assignment and display

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, display, spark-structured-streaming

I have following stream code in a databricks notebook (python).

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode
from pyspark.sql.functions import split

spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("MyTest") \
    .getOrCreate()

# Create a streaming DataFrame
lines = spark.readStream \
    .format("delta") \
    .table("myschema.streamTest")
```

In notebook 2, I have

```
def foreach_batch_function(df, epoch_id):
    test = df
    print(test['simplecolumn'])
    display(test['simplecolumn'])
    test['simplecolumn'].display

lines.writeStream.outputMode("append").foreachBatch(foreach_batch_function).format('console').start()
```

When I execute the above where can I see the output from the .display function? I looked inside the cluster driver logs and I don't see anything. I also don't see anything in the notebook itself when executed except a successfully initialized and executing stream. I do see that the dataframe parameter data is displayed in console but I am trying to see that assigning test was successful.

I am trying to carry out this manipulation as a precursor to time series operations over mini batches for real-time model scoring and in python - but I am struggling to get the basics right in the structured streaming world. A working model functions but executes every 10-15 minutes. I would like to make it realtime via streams and hence this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing different things together - I recommend to read initial parts of the [structured streaming documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html) or chapter 8 of Learning Spark, 2ed book (freely available from [here](https://databricks.com/p/ebook/learning-spark-from-oreilly)).

You can use [`display` function](https://docs.databricks.com/notebooks/visualizations/index.html#structured-streaming-dataframes) directly on the stream, like (better with `checkpointLocation` and maybe `trigger` parameters as described in documentation):

```
display(lines)
```

Regarding the scoring - usually it's done by defining the user defined function and applying it to stream either as `select` or `withColumn` functions of the dataframe.  Easiest way is to register a model in the MLflow registry, and then load model with built-in functions, like:

```
import mlflow.pyfunc

pyfunc_udf = mlflow.pyfunc.spark_udf(spark, model_uri=model_uri)
preds = lines.withColumn("predictions", pyfunc_udf(params...))
```

Look into that [notebook](https://docs.databricks.com/_static/notebooks/mlflow/mlflow-quick-start-inference.html) for examples.

Comment: Thank you for the book. Downloaded and on chapter 8 now. Also, thank you for the code snippet and the notebook example. I will go and try to make use of my model (sitting in mlflow registry at the moment)

Comment: Then it’s easy - model URI will be models://name/stage